# Different XML-related behaviour under Windows and Linux

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

In the open-source project [Rultor](https://github.com/yegor256/rultor). In that project there is a unit test [`com.rultor.agents.IndexesRequestsTest#retrievesIndexFromSibling`](https://github.com/yegor256/rultor/blob/master/src/test/java/com/rultor/agents/IndexesRequestsTest.java), which looks like this:

```
@Test
public void retrievesIndexFromSibling() throws Exception {
    final String first = "first";
    final Talks talks = new Talks.InDir();
    talks.create("", first);
    talks.get(first).modify(
        new Directives().xpath("/talk")
            .add("wire").add("href").set("#3").up().up()
            .add("archive")
            .add("log").attr("id", "3").attr("title", "title3")
            .attr("index", "1").up()
    );
    final String second = "second";
    talks.create("", second);
    talks.get(second).modify(
        new Directives().xpath("/talk")
            .add("wire").add("href").set("#4").up().up()
            .add("archive")
            .add("log").attr("id", "4").attr("title", "title4")
            .attr("index", "2").up()
    );
    final String third = "third";
    talks.create("", third);
    talks.get(third).modify(
        new Directives()
            .xpath("/talk").add("wire").add("href").set("#5").up().up()
            .add("request").attr("id", "a67890")
            .add("args").up()
            .add("type").set("merge").up()
    );
    new IndexesRequests().execute(talks);
    MatcherAssert.assertThat(
        talks.get(third).read(),
        XhtmlMatchers.hasXPaths("/talk/request[@index='5']")
    );
}
```

Now look at the call `talks.get(third).read()` at the end of the test.

Under Windows, its result is equal to

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<talk later="false" name="third" number="1" public="true">
   <wire>
      <href>#5</href>
   </wire>
   <request id="a67890" index="5">
      <args/>
      <type>merge</type>
   </request>
</talk>
```

Under Linux, the result of `talks.get(third).read()` is equal to

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<talk later="false" name="third" number="1" public="true">
   <wire>
      <href>#5</href>
   </wire>
   <request id="a67890" index="3">
      <args/>
      <type>merge</type>
   </request>
</talk>
```

Difference: Under Windows the `index` attribute of `request` is `5`, under Linux - `3`.

Why?

The class, which generates the index is [`com.rultor.agents.IndexesRequests`](https://github.com/yegor256/rultor/blob/master/src/main/java/com/rultor/agents/IndexesRequests.java):

```
public final class IndexesRequests implements SuperAgent {
    @Override
    public void execute(final Talks talks) throws IOException {
        int idx = this.index(talks);
        for (final Talk talk : talks.active()) {
            idx += 1;
            talk.modify(
                new Directives()
                    .xpath("/talk/request")
                    .attr("index", Integer.toString(idx))
            );
        }
    }

    /**
     * Calculates maximal index value for a {@link Talks} object.
     * @param talks The {@link Talks} object
     * @return The maximal index value
     * @throws IOException if the content of one {@link Talk} object can't be read
     */
    private int index(final Talks talks) throws IOException {
        int index = 0;
        for (final Talk talk : talks.active()) {
            final int idx = this.index(talk);
            if (idx > index) {
                index = idx;
            }
        }
        return index;
    }

    /**
     * Calculates maximal (existing) index value of a {@link Talk} object.
     * @param talk The {@link Talk} object
     * @return The maximal index value
     * @throws IOException if the content of the {@link Talk} object can't be read
     */
    private int index(final Talk talk) throws IOException {
        final Iterable<Integer> indexes = Iterables.transform(
                talk.read()
                .xpath("/talk/archive/log/@index|/talk/request/@index"),
            new Function<String, Integer>() {
                @Override
                public Integer apply(final String input) {
                    return Integer.parseInt(input);
                }
            }
        );
        final int index;
        if (indexes.iterator().hasNext()) {
            index = Ordering.natural().max(indexes);
        } else {
            index = 0;
        }
        return index;
    }
}
```

Are there any other places in the code, which may behave differently under Windows and Linux, apart from the XPath call in the `index` method?

**Update 1 (23.01.2015 14:47 MSK):** If I add

```
System.out.println("Index first: " +
    new IndexesRequests().index(talks.get(first)));
System.out.println("Index second: " +
    new IndexesRequests().index(talks.get(second)));
System.out.println("Index third: " +
    new IndexesRequests().index(talks.get(third)));
```

the results are the same for both Linux and Windows:

```
Index first: 1
Index second: 2
Index third: 0
```

After adding these diagnostic messages, the test doesn't fail under Linux.

**Update 2 (23.01.2015 15:07 MSK):**

I added the code for printing out the `talks.active()` result.

```
final Iterable<Talk> activeTalks = talks.active();

System.out.println("activeTalks (START)");

for (final Talk talk : activeTalks) {
    System.out.println("Talk XML: " + talk.read().toString());
}

System.out.println("activeTalks (END)");
```

Windows:

```
activeTalks (START)
Talk XML: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<talk later="false" name="first" number="1" public="true">
   <wire>
      <href>#3</href>
   </wire>
   <archive>
      <log id="3" index="1" title="title3"/>
   </archive>
</talk>
Talk XML: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<talk later="false" name="second" number="1" public="true">
   <wire>
      <href>#4</href>
   </wire>
   <archive>
      <log id="4" index="2" title="title4"/>
   </archive>
</talk>
Talk XML: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<talk later="false" name="third" number="1" public="true">
   <wire>
      <href>#5</href>
   </wire>
   <request id="a67890">
      <args/>
      <type>merge</type>
   </request>
</talk>
activeTalks (END)
```

Linux:

```
activeTalks (START)
Talk XML: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<talk later="false" name="third" number="1" public="true">
   <wire>
      <href>#5</href>
   </wire>
   <request id="a67890">
      <args/>
      <type>merge</type>
   </request>
</talk>
Talk XML: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<talk later="false" name="second" number="1" public="true">
   <wire>
      <href>#4</href>
   </wire>
   <archive>
      <log id="4" index="2" title="title4"/>
   </archive>
</talk>
Talk XML: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<talk later="false" name="first" number="1" public="true">
   <wire>
      <href>#3</href>
   </wire>
   <archive>
      <log id="3" index="1" title="title3"/>
   </archive>
</talk>
activeTalks (END)
```

Comment: Are you sure you are using exactly the same version?

Comment: The fluent API in talks.get(third).modify(...) doesn't set request/@index - I'm surprised how you get those outputs showing index="3" or "5".

Comment: @laune `talks.get(third).modify(...)` in the unit test isn't supposed to add an `index` attribute. That attribute is supposed to be set in `IndexesRequests.execute`.

Comment: What does talks.active() return? Is the ordering of this collection deterministic?

Comment: @laune See update 2.

Comment: This leads me to think that what Talks.active() returns is based on a hashed something and grabbing the elements doesn't return them in a deterministic order. - Isn't Talks one of your app classes?

Comment: @laune I added sorting in `Talks.active` and now it seems to work. You can submit your hint as an answer and I'll accept it. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your algorithm for computing the @index depends on the order of these elements being delivered by talks.active(). If this returns the values of a say, HashMap or HashSet, they may be returned in one order on this system, and in another order on that system.

Defining a hashCode may not produce a reliable order.

One reliable way would be a Map or Set maintaining the order of insertion (as in LinkedHash*).